# Syntax error in Insert Into access database

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I am trying to make a project and i need to register user using class but     when i run the code its give SYNTAX ERROR IN INSERT STATEMENT.

```
class LG 
{
    Connection MainConnection = new Connection();
    public static string _password;
    public static string _username;
    string username;
    string password;

    public LG (string username, string password)
    { 
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void add()
    {
        string query = "insert into LG (Username,Password)values('" +                                  
         username + "','" + password + "')";
        OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(query,  
        MainConnection.getConnect());
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
```

Comment: learn to use `Parameterized Query` look up what is `SQL Injection` also wrap reserved words in your fields names like the following `([Username], [Password])`

Answer (score -1):

```
//Try this out...  
  class LG 
    {
        Connection MainConnection = new Connection();
        public static string _password;
        public static string _username;
        string username;
        string password;

        public LG (string username, string password)
        { 
            this.username = username;
            this.password = password;
        }

        public void add()
        {
            string query = "insert into LG (Username,[Password])values('" +                                  
             username + "','" + password+ "')";
            OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(query,  
           MainConnection.getConnect());
           com.ExecuteNonQuery();
          //close connection here
           MainConnection.Dispose();
         }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try escape sequences:

```
string query = "insert into LG (Username,Password)values(\'\" + username + \"\',\'\" + password + \"\')";
```

Answer (score -1):

try to use String format something like

```
 string query = string.Format("insert into LG (Username,Password) values('{0}','{1}', username, Password)";
```